# videos are running too fast

Tags: graphics, video, 14.04

I am very new to Linux, facing a very different problem of running videos on Ubuntu 14.04

While watching videos the frame rate is three times faster, than the original speed i.e. the shot of time duration 3 seconds is been shown in just a single second.

Please help me!

Comment: Do you hear any sound? Is your sound perhaps redirected to a HDMI output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Adobe Flash Player and try again (for YouTube and other Web videos).
(Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras from the software center)