# Videos/Musics plays so fast on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, video, vlc

Why is it that the videos I play in my browser play so fast?

Even when I play some of my videos using `vlc` and Spotify, they all play so fast, and now I cannot even hear what they are saying. How can I fix this?

I already tried this [videos are running too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455230/videos-are-running-too-fast) but nothing happens.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why this is happening. It's because I changed something in sound settings.

To change it back to normal, I went to **Settings > Sound** and chose **Speakers (Built-in Audio)** in the **Output** tab instead of **HDMI/Display Port** Now it all works like a breeze :D